# React admin throws "can't convert undefined to object" on custom dataprovider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-admin

Using custom dataprovider available from the tutorials, where I also added a custom data request, which we can call "fetchData", which just asks certain endpoint for data.
It works with default admin interface, but it fails with said error on custom admin UI.

More details:

```
TypeError: can't convert undefined to object

isDataProviderOptions
node_modules/ra-core/esm/dataProvider/getDataProviderCallArguments.js:19

  16 | ];
  17 | var isDataProviderOptions = function (value) {
  18 |     var options = value;
> 19 |     return Object.keys(options).some(function (key) { return OptionsProperties.includes(key); });
  20 | };
  21 | // As all dataProvider methods do not have the same signature, we must differentiate
  22 | // standard methods which have the (resource, params, options) signature
```

I guess it requires some "options". And I tried to add them from given open source examples of dataprovider so far with no luck.

The value of options is "undefined", as expected.

The code of my dataprovider: https://pastebin.com/VMrhdSTB
But mind you - it's from tutorial with little modifications.

+++

How do I use this dataprovider:

```
import { number } from 'prop-types';
import * as React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { AdminContext, AdminUI, Resource, ListGuesser, useDataProvider } from 'react-admin';

import DataProvider from './dataprovider';

function App() {
    return (
        <AdminContext dataProvider={DataProvider}>
            <AsyncResources />
        </AdminContext>
    );
}

function AsyncResources() {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
      stations_info: {
        data: [
          {
            id: number,
            ip: "",
            name: "",
            port: number
          }
        ],
        total: number
      }
    });
    const dataProvider = useDataProvider();

    useEffect(() => {
        dataProvider.fetchStations().then(
          stations_info => {
            setState(
                state => ({...state, stations_info })
            )
        }
        
        )}, []);

    const StationResources = () => {
      const { data, total } = state.stations_info;
 
      let render_items = []
  
      for (var item of data) {
          render_items.push(<Resource
            name={item.name}
            key={item.key}
            list={ListGuesser}
          />)
      }
  
      return (
              <div>
                  {render_items.map(item => item)}
              </div>
      )
    }

    return (
        <AdminUI>
            { StationResources }
        </AdminUI>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of  **options** in the console by logging it? If yes, was it an Object?

Comment: Please include more information

Comment: @Darkshadow Yes, I tried that. No success.

Comment: @UKS What information do you want? I maybe just need to share the dataprovider code with you and that's it.

Comment: You can include it in the question. And also what is the console value of  `options` inside that method?

Comment: @UKS the value is undefined, as expected. And I've included the source code of my provider here: https://pastebin.com/VMrhdSTB  
Will also attach this information to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in react-admin 3.10.0, which is already fixed in master. The fix will be released in version 3.10.1, (scheduled today).

https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/5524